# How do I install Anything-sync-daemon?

Tags: installation, performance, ssd, porting

From the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Anything-sync-daemon):

> [`Anything-sync-daemon`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?K=Anything-sync-daemon&SeB=x) (asd) is a tiny shell script designed to manage target directories in tmpfs and to periodically sync them back to your physical disc (HDD/SSD). This is accomplished via a symlinking step and an innovative use of rsync to maintain back-up and synchronization between the two. One of the major design goals of asd is a completely transparent user experience.

What would it take to use this in Ubuntu?

Comment: I have submitted a [packaging request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1054251) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would take an upstart `/etc/init` conf script. The upstream repository now includes an [Upstart init script designed specifically for Ubuntu](https://github.com/graysky2/anything-sync-daemon/blob/master/init/asd.ubuntu).

[goanysync](https://github.com/wor/goanysync) is a program with similar
functionality to `asd` and includes upstart init script and a pre-build deb 
package for testing. Packaging it properly for Ubuntu should be quite easy.

Also just taking goanysyncs upstart conf file and using it with slight modification for `asd` should work.